# I can not run my AWS/EC2 server in the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got a t2.micro (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server) from amazon and I installed tomcat7 in the server. I have an elastic public IP for the server which is: XX.XX.XX.XXX. After finishing the installation, I put in the browser http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080/manager. Firefox stays in a loop until it get stopped. I also checked the ping for XX.XX.XX.XXX and the outcome was just:
XX.XX.XX.XXX (XX.XX.XX.XXX) 56(84) bytes of data. That was it.
Could someone give me a tip on this issue?
Thank you for your time in advance
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your EC2 security group and it will work

[image]

Comment: Hi @error2007s, thank you for your reply. I have done that, but even my Public DNS (http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/) is not working. Is there anything else related to this issue?  This is my security groups configuration:  
HTTP                           TCP         80          0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule         TCP         8080       0.0.0.0/0
All traffic                       All           All           sg-34013c52 (default)
SSH                             TCP          22          0.0.0.0/0
DNS (UDP)                    UDP         53          0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Are you using Apache? If yes can you paste the configuration file.

Comment: I haven't installed Apache, @error2007s. Is it necessary to install it in order to have the public DNS working?